# SQL Query - For Count of Records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've one table named "**history**" (Column Names are: ID, Records, Stage, Date) where I've the following records:

```
1    Record1    Stage1  Date
2    Record2    Stage1  Date
3    Record3    Stage1  Date
4    Record1    Stage2  Date
```

all that Records having some priority saved in master table named as "**Records**" (Column names are: id, Record, Stagename, date) like as shown below

```
1   Record1 High    Date    
2   Record2 Low Date
3   Record3 Medium  Date
upto more than 100+ records
```

So i want to show the COUNT of High Low and Medium 
Desired Output:

**[#] For Stage 1**

```
High - 1
Low - 1
Medium -1
```

**[#] For Stage 2**

```
High - 1
Low - 0
Medium - 0
```

Could you please help me into this?

Here what my code is:

```
$stagename = "Stage 1";
$query= $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM history WHERE stagename=?");
$stmt->execute(array($getstagename));
$count= $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the column names (since you didn't include them), but the query should go like this:

```
select
  h.stage,
  r.priority,
  count(*)
from history h
join records r on r.record_name = h.record_name
group by h.stage, r.priority
order by h.stage, r.priority
```